# if else code blocks ... or one if with multiple OR ( | |) conditions within it ? in C

Tags: c, string, performance, if-statement

I was writing a small text matching program in C, which basically checks for the presence of a few characters in some strings (in form of char arrays). Its working now and I have a code block like this:

```
if (c == 'A') return 1;
else if (c == 'B') return 1;
else if (c == 'C') return 1;
....
....
else if (c == 'Z') return 1;
else return 0;
```

Is the block above faster? Or would this be faster?

```
if (c == 'A' || c == 'B' || c == 'C' ||....|| c == 'Z') return 1;
else return 0;
```

By fast I mean literally fast, i.e. if I run a simple timer from the start of the program till the end which could potentially give a shorter execution time?

Comment: It is all the same in the eyes of a good optimizing compiler.

Comment: Just run a benchmark and see for yourself.

Comment: I doubt any loss would get through the optimizer.

Comment: Check the compiler's output. It will probably be the same for both cases.

Comment: BTW, `char` is a keyword for a type. You should not use it as an identifier.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: **Should not**? I would like to know how it is they claim to “have a code block like this”. I think it is more than should not. How about must not? Unless they have used `#define` to change `char`. Shudder.

Comment: I'm simply not a native English speaker. I mean that it is forbidden to use `char` as a variable identifier.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Sorry, I was not criticizing your language, just expressing incredulity that the OP claimed to be using `char` as an identifier. I am dismayed at the frequency with which posters do not copy and paste actual code which they have submitted to a compiler but instead introduce errors with newly fabricated code. Sure, back in the 1970s and even 1980s we had to retype things, but isn’t that passé now?

Comment: Hi Sorry about the char. I have many diff functions in that form. so maybe I had char on top of my mind ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that you shouldn't worry about these small performance issues if you are not sure it is really worth it.

In any case, if you want to check for any A-Z letter then this **(mind that this makes an assumption about the encoding of character used which shouldn't have any external symbol between `A` and `Z` or this won't work)**

```
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
```

is surely a simpler way.

Don't forget that for long if else chains over expression values you can even use `switch` statements:

```
switch (exp) {
  case 'A':
  case 'B':
  case 'C':
  ...
    return 1;
  default: return 0;
}
```

A `switch` can be marginally faster in certain situations because, depending on the compiler, it could use a lookup table, but we are really talking about microseconds.

For sake of completeness, C standard library has two methods `isupper` and `isalpha` which can be used:

```
if (isupper(c)) // c is an alphabetic uppercase character
```

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee that no characters other than uppercase letters have values between `'A'` and `'Z'`, so comparing in this way is not proper unless there is an additional guarantee about the character set in the particular C implementation being used. Also, an identifier cannot have the name `char`, since it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @JensGustedt: with `-std=c99` on gcc 4.2.1 it compiles and works fine without any empty statement `;`, which standard are you referring to?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: While technically true, practically nobody these days writes code to be compatible with such systems (e.g. EBCDIC).  For all practical purposes, it's a pretty safe assumption that the characters between `'A'` and `'Z'` are exactly the 26 uppercase letters and nothing more.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: It's a reasonably safe assumption, but not a *necessary* one given the existence of `isupper()` (though `isupper()`'s behavior can vary depending on the current locale).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: This is just being picky with no reason to do it. This code works in the 99.5% of the situations, an assumption over the encoding must be done externally when writing code about this butit is rather unusual to have to work with encodings which have other symbols between `A` and `Z`

Comment: @Jack: I disagree; there are good reasons for being this picky. 1.By writing code that's 100% correct rather than just 99.5% correct, you have fewer things to worry about when bugs inevitably appear. 2. It's most likely to fail on EBCDIC-based systems, and yes, they still exist. If somebody ports your code to an IBM mainframe, you probably wont have access to it, making it that much harder to fix. 3. ASCII vs. EBCDIC isn't the only issue; there are far more than 26 uppercase letters -- and `isupper` should handle all of them correctly. "What do you mean `Â` isn't an uppercase letter"?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Engineering consists of deriving desired behavior from specifications. Assumptions should be avoided, especially when there are known counterexamples and easy alternatives. Encouraging sloppy programming does **not** belong in a tutorial environment.

Comment: @Jack: Are you going to document this assumption? One way that failures occur is somebody writes code, states it is C, and, years later, somebody else adopts it to another purpose, relying on the statement that it is C. But, with the undocumented assumption, it fails on the new system. Unfortunately, sometimes failures are not found in testing, but are found when human beings are relying on a system to work. Contrary to your assertion that there is no reason to be picky about this, there is **no reason not to be**, because there are proper alternatives easily available.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I edited my answer to be clear about this aspect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree that assumptions should be avoided when at all possible -- obviously `isupper(c)` should be preferred to `(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')`.  But what about more complicated procedures, like iterating over all uppercase basic Latin letters?  Do you write loops like `for(int c = 0; c < (1<<CHAR_BIT); c++) { if(isupper(c)) /*...*/ }` or just `for(int c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) { /*...*/ }`?  I really hope that anybody still writing code for non-ASCII IBM mainframes understands what they're doing and isn't copying code off of StackOverflow.

Comment: This seems like a more complete answer along with the comments. I am not exactly trying to check for A to Z ... rather a range of ascii values which may or may not include A to Z depending on the functions. And YES it is worth it, with the amount of data I need to handle, every little drop counts to the end performance.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: How do you know when you are writing code for non-ASCII IBM systems or non-ASCII systems (e.g., BS2000/OSD or MPE/iX)? If you write source code for one customer with an agreement that it is designed for a specific target machine and they do not have permission to port it anywhere else, and you document all that, fine. You might hope nobody copies off Stack Overflow to EBDIC systems, but you are teaching people. And it is much harder to deal with false assumptions years later, after they have been written into code that is thought to be portable, than it is to teach correctly.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: If you need to iterate over A-Z, you can document character set requirements in your software specification, you can embed assertions in the build process of the software, or you can write software that is reasonably efficient even though it does not make assumptions about the character set beyond what is guaranteed by the language.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend doing the following:

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

return isupper(c)
```

Instead of manually checking all of them. The standard C library functions are reasonably fast so performance should be acceptable.

Comment: +1,but before begging to use `is*()` functions from `ctype.h` keep on mind the Basile Starynkevitch's note.

Comment: I am not actually checking for whether the letter is in capital or small case, it was just a representation of what I am trying to do. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4):

An optimizing compiler will handle both forms likewise.

<sup>Leave such micro-optimizations to the compiler. What also matters is the readability of your source code.</sup>

(Of course you need to enable optimizations, for [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) -e.g. the recent GCC 4.8- you'll compile with `gcc -O2`).

And you really need to benchmark to be sure (because tons of other factors also matter: in particular cache locality) what is the best. You could even use some more fancy algorithms (e.g. testing more frequent letters, like `E`, before rare ones like `Z`). Look for [search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree) for more.

Look for instance into the generated assembly code (use `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S` to get it) or look into the internal representations, e.g. using the [the MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id) (or passing `-fdump-tree-all` -giving many dump files to you- to `gcc`).

With GCC extensions, for your specific example, you could even code [case ranges](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges) like this:

```
 switch (c) {
    case 'A' ... 'Z': return 1;
    default: return 0;
 }
```

<sup>the above case range assmes that the character encoding is a superset of [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). It won't work for [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)</sup>

Actually, *switch optimization* is complex. See [this paper](http://nextmovesoftware.com/technology/SwitchOptimization.pdf) etc....

And actually, you want to use [isalpha(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) from `<ctype.h>` (in the C99 standard).

<sup>Testing what is a letter is not that simple: Is `é` or `И` a latter for you? For me it is one (they both are vowels and both need more than one byte in UTF8)</sup>

Be cautious about the common [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding: some letters (notably from non English languages or alphabet) are encoded with several bytes. Look e.g. at [Glib Unicode Manipulation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a larger number of conditions, a switch block would be better:

```
switch(c) {
   case 'A':
   case 'B':
   // (...)
   case 'Z': return 1;
   default: return 0;
}
```

Comment: The switch statement in the answer is correct; you can have multiple `case` labels followed by a statement. You've made the same error in comments on other answers.

Comment: oops, sorry, I was confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

Without entering in the scope of compiler optimization, assembly generation and better algorithms, what other posters missed is that the single if with multiple test cases and multiple ORs (`||`) will short-circuit after the first match. Effectively, the first and the second snippets of code will generate equivalent ASM in terms of speed.

Answer (score -1):

As other mentioned,makes no different. The same count of `cmp` instructions will be generated in both `if`s conditions(it is not considering any optmization by compiler)

**EDIT:**

Consider this **C** functions:

```
int is_letter2(int c)
{
  if(c == 'A') return 1;
  else if(c == 'B') return 1;
  else if(c == 'C') return 1;
  else if(c == 'D') return 1;
  else if(c == 'E') return 1;
  else if(c == 'F') return 1;
  else if(c == 'G') return 1;
  else if(c == 'H') return 1;
  else if(c == 'I') return 1;
  else if(c == 'J') return 1;
  else if(c == 'K') return 1;
  else if(c == 'L') return 1;
  else if(c == 'M') return 1;
  else if(c == 'N') return 1;
  else if(c == 'O') return 1;
  else if(c == 'P') return 1;
  else if(c == 'Q') return 1;
  else if(c == 'R') return 1;
  else if(c == 'S') return 1;
  else if(c == 'T') return 1;
  else if(c == 'U') return 1;
  else if(c == 'V') return 1;
  else if(c == 'W') return 1;
  else if(c == 'X') return 1;
  else if(c == 'Y') return 1;
  else if(c == 'Z') return 1;
  else return 0;
}

int is_letter(int c)
{
  if(c == 'A' ||c == 'B' ||c == 'C' ||c == 'D' ||c == 'E' ||c == 'F' ||c == 'G' ||c == 'H' ||c == 'I' ||c == 'J' ||c == 'K' ||c == 'L' ||c == 'M' ||c == 'N' ||c == 'O' ||c == 'P' ||c == 'Q' ||c == 'R' ||c == 'S' ||c == 'T' ||c == 'U' ||c == 'V' ||c == 'W' ||c == 'X' ||c == 'Y' ||c == 'Z')
    return 1;
 else return 0;
}
```

And the **assembly** output: It's almost the **same**. Check out:

```
is_letter2:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    cmpl    $65, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L3
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L3:
    cmpl    $66, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L5
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    cmpl    $67, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L6
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L6:
    cmpl    $68, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L7
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L7:
    cmpl    $69, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L8
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L8:
    cmpl    $70, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L9
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L9:
    cmpl    $71, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L10
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L10:
    cmpl    $72, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L11
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L11:
    cmpl    $73, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L12
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L12:
    cmpl    $74, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L13
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L13:
    cmpl    $75, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L14
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L14:
    cmpl    $76, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L15
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L15:
    cmpl    $77, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L16
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L16:
    cmpl    $78, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L17
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L17:
    cmpl    $79, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L18
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L18:
    cmpl    $80, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L19
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L19:
    cmpl    $81, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L20
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L20:
    cmpl    $82, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L21
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L21:
    cmpl    $83, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L22
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L22:
    cmpl    $84, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L23
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L23:
    cmpl    $85, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L24
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L24:
    cmpl    $86, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L25
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L25:
    cmpl    $87, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L26
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L26:
    cmpl    $88, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L27
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L27:
    cmpl    $89, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L28
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L28:
    cmpl    $90, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L29
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L4
.L29:
    movl    $0, %eax
.L4:
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    .cfi_restore 5
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   is_letter2, .-is_letter2
    .globl  is_letter
    .type   is_letter, @function
is_letter:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    cmpl    $65, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $66, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $67, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $68, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $69, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $70, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $71, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $72, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $73, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $74, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $75, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $76, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $77, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $78, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $79, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $80, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $81, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $82, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $83, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $84, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $85, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $86, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $87, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $88, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $89, 8(%ebp)
    je  .L31
    cmpl    $90, 8(%ebp)
    jne .L32
.L31:
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L33
.L32:
    movl    $0, %eax
.L33:
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    .cfi_restore 5
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

In resume,it's the same program.